# How to Understand and Fix Reason of Skipped Tests Due To Cucumber dryRun Validation Errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, cucumber

I have defined my Cucumber context class as;

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "com.a.dummy.bdd.steps",
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"},
        strict = true,
        dryRun = true
)
public class CucumberTest {
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
public class PingTest {

    @When("^the client calls /ping")
    public void the_client_calls_GET_ping() {
    }

    @Then("^the client receives status code of (\\d+)$")
    public void the_client_receives_status_code_of(int statusCode) {
    }

    @And("^the client receives request date")
    public void the_client_receives_request_date() {
    }
}
```

This is my `ping.feature` definition:

```
Feature: the application responds the ping request

  Scenario: client makes call to GET /ping
    When the client calls /ping
    Then the client receives status code of 200
    And the client receives request date
```

Cucumber test is skipped due to dryRun is set to true. There is no log message about why validation failed.

Output:

```
2020-04-02 19:09:09.246  INFO 4156 --- [           main] c.a.dummy.DummyApplicationTests      : Started DummyApplicationTests in 4.883 seconds (JVM running for 5.991)
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.323 s - in com.a.dummy.DummyApplicationTests
[INFO] Running com.a.dummy.bdd.CucumberTest

Scenario: client makes call to GET /ping      # src/test/resources/features/ping.feature:3
  When the client calls /ping                 # com.a.dummy.bdd.steps.PingTest.the_client_calls_GET_ping()
  Then the client receives status code of 200 # com.a.dummy.bdd.steps.PingTest.the_client_receives_status_code_of(int)
  And the client receives request date        # com.a.dummy.bdd.steps.PingTest.the_client_receives_request_date()

1 Scenarios (1 skipped)
3 Steps (3 skipped)
0m0.149s


[WARNING] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.149 s - in com.a.dummy.bdd.CucumberTest
2020-04-02 19:09:09.515  INFO 4156 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-02 19:09:09.520  INFO 4156 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-02 19:09:09.520  INFO 4156 --- [extShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2020-04-02 19:09:09.531  INFO 4156 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-04-02 19:09:09.535  INFO 4156 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[WARNING] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.380 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-02T19:09:10+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I understand underlying reason and fix it for my case?

**PS 1:** I use Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE, Cucumber 5.5.0, JUnit 5 without excluding vintage.

**PS 2:** 2 tests are run. One of them is default Spring Boot Application test which is a JUnit test.

Comment: What did you expect to fail?

Comment: I don't expect anything to fail. Test is skipped and I wonder why it has skipped.

Comment: Because you've enabled dry-run?